# how to hash passwords in phpmyadmin with bcrypt config

Tags: mysql, laravel, hash, phpmyadmin, bcrypt

I need some help figuring out how to solve this, here's the thing:

I have imported a list of users from a csv file in my database, however, I want to create some new passwords for all of them using bcrypt, since I'm using laravel and I use bcrypt to store passwords when I create or update a password value from there. So, I don't know if there's any possibility to make a SQL query to hash them all, create a script, or hash them one by one. I'm kinda new to using advanced phpmyadmin functions. All help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use this function to hash your password

Comment: Thanks, but i have a question: how can I alter all registries in a table?, because they're more than 10,000 rows to modify

Comment: I think you might have to write an importer in php .
I have an experiance with this elegant package 
https://laravel-excel.com/
it is very handy